# flex + min-height = grandchild of 0 height

Tags: html, css

The innermost child div has a height of 0 even though its parent does not have a height of 0.

However, if I change the css property min-height to simply height in the topmost div then the innermost div takes up the whole screen (as expected)

Why does height and min-height behave differently in the topmost div?

```
<body>
    <div style="
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;">
        <div style="flex: 1">
            <div style="height: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Setting the `min-height` is not the same as setting an explicit height, therefore the child won't inherit it as it would a static height.

Comment: FYI @justDan there's no point in creating a Stack Snippet if you don't also insert some styles or content to *illustrate* the thing. Without that, having a runnable demo tells us nothing beyond looking at the code itself.